# How to get all fields of expression in Java? And what is the most efficient way?

Tags: java, sql

How to get all fields of expression?  And what is the most efficient way?

For example:

```
(field_1+field_2)*field_3
```

the result will be java list:

```
[field_1, field_2, field_3]
```

---

> I know one way:
>
> ```
> ExpressRunner runner = new ExpressRunner();
> String[] ret = runner.getOutVarNames("a+b*c");
> ```
>
> maven:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
>   <artifactId>QLExpress</artifactId>
>   <version>3.2.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

---

**ADD**

The scenario is about `SQL select` parser. In `SQL`, like this:

```
select  (field_1+field_2)*field_3 as ret1, (field_4-field_5) as ret2
from table_1
```

I got `(field_1+field_2)*field_3` and `(field_4-field_5)`. And I want to get all fields in `(field_1+field_2)*field_3` or `(field_4-field_5)`.

Comment: `string.split("[+()*]")`.

Comment: by what do you define *expression*?

Comment: What are you going to do with them when you have them? Do you intend to evaluate the expression? If so, you will need to write a proper scanner and parser.

Comment: The scenario is about `SQL select` parser. I update the question.  @AndyTurner @Lino @EJP

Comment: First, you need to know what fields are allowed. Typically, it can consist of letters, digits and underscores). Depending on the conventions, it usually can start with a letter or a underscore. Then, you need to know which operations are allowed. I guess +, -, * and / are suuported. What about functions like `min`, `max`, `sqrt`, etc.
Can you explain a bit more how your expressions are defined?

Comment: `+, -, *, /`  and `min`, `max`, `sqrt` etc should be supported.  I couldn't enumerate all cases. It should support the clause before `AS` in `MySql`. @BrunoL

Comment: And the question remains 'what are you going to do with them when you have them'. In other words, *why*? Why don't you know the fields in your own query? or the columns in your own SQL database?

Comment: I am developing `Heterogeneous Data Query System`. And I describe the output fields like `(field_1+field_2)*field_3`. The fields are needed in `DataSource Layer `. `field_1` will be translated to `table_1.field_1`. So `(field_1+field_2)*field_3` will be  translated to  `(table_1.field_1+table_1.field_2)*table_2.field_3`.  @EJP

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, which is pretty naive, would be to split the string:

```
String[] fields = Stream.of(string.split("[+()*]"))
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

But this is pretty naive, and may well break down for some of your inputs. Depends upon how you define your "expression". You might have to write a parser.

Comment: That's pretty naive